# I am trying to run a bioinfo program (Simple Synteny), but it just won't initiatialize Magick

Tags: ruby, rmagick

The program can be found in: https://www.dveltri.com/simplesynteny/versions/

I'm running the SyntenyDrawer.rb

with the lines:

```
sudo ruby ~/GenomasdeTribolium/SimpleSynteny_LATEST/SyntenyDrawer.rb ~/GenomasdeTribolium/demofiles/cmap
```

Keep getting this answer:

```
Checking for CMAP Files in DIR: /home/vieira/GenomasdeTribolium/demofiles/cmap
Found: teste1_fwd.cmap
Found: teste2_fwd.cmap
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /home/vieira/GenomasdeTribolium/SimpleSynteny_LATEST/SyntenyDrawer.rb:1442:in `<main>'
    2: from /home/vieira/GenomasdeTribolium/SimpleSynteny_LATEST/SyntenyDrawer.rb:1442:in `new'
    1: from /home/vieira/GenomasdeTribolium/SimpleSynteny_LATEST/SyntenyDrawer.rb:1442:in `initialize'
/home/vieira/GenomasdeTribolium/SimpleSynteny_LATEST/SyntenyDrawer.rb:1442:in `block in <main>': undefined method `density=' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I have installed the packages via:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev

sudo apt-get install ruby

gem install --user rmagick (and also add the PATH via export PATH="/home/vieira/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin:$PATH" and then gem install --user rmagick and also tried gem install rmagik)

gem install --user bio (also performed the same procedure as above)
```

The lines regarding the error are:

```
line 36:  require 'rmagick'
line 37:  include Magick

line 1442: canvas = Magick::Image.new(img_width, img_height) {self.density = $DPI}
```

Can anyone figure out how to solve it? Please?

I was trying to run the program to build an image file with the relevant details for genomic analysis.

Comment: there is a bug, `self` does not have the property `density`. maybe you need to install a specific version of rmagic or of one of the other dependencies. ask the person who has written the installation document what versions are required to run it. this should have been part of the documentation (actually providing a Gemfile or the likes)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried to reach the developer, but I got no reply. The documentation don't mention any version for this program. Maybe it really is dependent of one specific but I can't know. Thanks again for the reply!